# Python - Loop Escaping unexpectedly and not iterating over list as expected

Tags: python, loops

```
import random
import time
def closest_num(GuessesLog, CompNum):
    return GuessesLog[min(range(len(GuessesLog)), key=lambda g: abs(GuessesLog[g] - CompNum))]
GameModeActive = True
while GameModeActive:
    Guesses = None
    GuessesLog = []
    while not isinstance(Guesses, int):
        try:
            Guesses = int(input("How many guesses do you have?: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a whole number")  
            print(" ")        
    CompNum = random.randint(1,99)
    print(CompNum)
    Players = None
    while not isinstance(Players, int):
        try:
            Players = int(input("How many players are there?: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a whole number") 
            print(" ")            
    NumberOfPlayers = []
    for i in range(Players):      
        NumberOfPlayers.append(i+1)    
    NumberOfGuesses = []
    for i in range(Guesses):
        NumberOfGuesses.append(i+1)        
    print(NumberOfGuesses)
    print(NumberOfPlayers)
    print(len(NumberOfGuesses))
    print(len(NumberOfPlayers))
    for Guess in NumberOfGuesses:        
        if Guess != len(NumberOfGuesses):
            print("ITS ROUND {}! GET READY!".format(Guess))
            print(" ") 
            PlayersForRound = NumberOfPlayers
            for Player in PlayersForRound:
                print("It is Player {}'s Turn >>>".format(Player))
                print(PlayersForRound)
                print(NumberOfPlayers)
                PlayerEntry = None
                while not isinstance(PlayerEntry, int):
                    try:
                        PlayerEntry = int(input("Enter guess number {}: ".format(Guess)))
                        print(" ")
                    except ValueError:
                        print("Please enter a whole number")
                print("CALCULATING YOUR RESULT!")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("***5***")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("***4***")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("***3***")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("***2***")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("***1***")
                if PlayerEntry == CompNum:
                    print("Congratulations player {}, you have successfully guessed the number on round {}!".format(Player, Guess))
                    print(" ")
                    NumberOfPlayers.pop(Player-1)
                    if len(NumberOfPlayers) == 1:
                        print("Only {} Player remains".format(len(NumberOfPlayers)))
                        PlayersForRound
                    elif len(NumberOfPlayers) > 1:
                        print("Only {} Players remain".format(len(NumberOfPlayers)))    
                    continue
                elif PlayerEntry < CompNum:
                    print("Your guess was too low!")
                    print(" ")
                    GuessesLog.append(PlayerEntry)
                    continue
                elif PlayerEntry > CompNum:
                    print("Your guess was too high!")
                    print(" ")
                    GuessesLog.append(PlayerEntry)                    
                    continue                                        
        if Guess == len(NumberOfGuesses):
            print("ITS ROUND {}! THIS IS THE LAST ROUND! GOOD LUCK!".format(Guess))
            print(" ")                                           
            print(NumberOfGuesses)
            print(NumberOfPlayers)
            print(len(NumberOfGuesses))
            print(len(NumberOfPlayers))                                          
            PlayersForRound = NumberOfPlayers
            for Player in PlayersForRound:
                print("It is Player {}'s Turn >>>".format(Player))
                PlayerEntry = None
                while not isinstance(PlayerEntry, int):
                    try:
                        PlayerEntry = int(input("Enter guess number {}: ".format(Guess)))
                        print(" ")
                    except ValueError:
                        print("Please enter a whole number")
                print("CALCULATING YOUR RESULT!")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("***5***")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("***4***")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("***3***")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("***2***")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("***1***")
                if PlayerEntry == CompNum:
                    print("Congratulations player {}, you have successfully guessed the number on round {}!".format(Player, Guess))
                    print(" ")
                    NumberOfPlayers.pop(Player-1)
                    if len(NumberOfPlayers) == 1:
                        print("Only {} Player remains".format(len(NumberOfPlayers)))
                    elif len(NumberOfPlayers) > 1:
                        print("Only {} Players remain".format(len(NumberOfPlayers)))    
                    continue
                elif PlayerEntry < CompNum:
                    print("Your guess was too low!")
                    print(" ")
                    GuessesLog.append(PlayerEntry)
                    continue
                elif PlayerEntry > CompNum:
                    print("Your guess was too high!")
                    print(" ")
                    GuessesLog.append(PlayerEntry)
                    continue
    print("The closest guess was ", closest_num(GuessesLog, CompNum)) 
    print(" ")
    while True:       
        Answer = input("Would you like to play again? Y/N: ")
        if Answer.lower() not in ('y', 'n'):
            print("Please enter either Y for Yes, or N for No.")
        else:
            break
    if Answer == 'y':
        GameActiveMode = True        
    elif Answer == 'n':
        GameActiveMode = False
        print("Thankyou for playing ;)")       
        break                        
holdCall = str(input("Holding the console, press enter to escape."))
```

In my above code, when there are multiple players and multiple guesses(Rounds) then it works fine unless someone successfully guesses the code. If the code is guessed the code deletes the correct record from the player list. But for some reason fails to iterate over the rest of the list or if the correct guess comes from the second user it skips the next player altogether and moves onto the next round.

I have absolutely no idea why. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

For example, if you run this in console and then have 3 guesses with 3 users, on the first player you guess incorrectly. On the second you guess correctly, it skips player 3 and goes straight to round 2. Despite only remove player 2 from the list after a correct guess.

Or if you guess it correctly the first time around it skips to the 3rd player?

Comment: Variable names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: It is *really* hard to figure out what's going on because of very confusing naming and incorrect use of the various data structures. I think your problem is on this line `NumberOfPlayers.pop(Player-1)`, because `Player` is actually a number and you're asking python to pop `Player - 1` elements from `NumberOfPlayers`. But considering that `NumberOfPlayers` is really a list of numbers of individual players (that don't really serve a purpose), I think you would do well to start by renaming your variables, following common naming conventions and then have another look at what's going on.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Thanks for that lol

Comment: @Grismar I appreciate the naming conventions are unusual, the player -1 is because the argument passed to the pop command is the index, and since the contents of the list is index +1 you have to index -1 to get the true index for the current instance. Its just converting a human read index to a machine read index in this case.

Comment: To be perfectly honest: it's just really, really bad code - so your issues are not really surprising. Cleaning up naming and having the naming actually match the meaning of the variables will make finding the issue a lot easier.

Comment: @Grismar i guess i dont really know what you mean, short of underscores or capital letters, they all make perfect sense to me. What would you suggest i changed?

Comment: I would tend to agree with @Grismar. I will try to write a fully refactored version tomorrow.

Comment: So, here's your problem (going along with your assumption the naming is fine, although I would recommend reading PEP8): you are looping over `PlayersForRound` with `for Player in PlayersForRound`, which is a list of indices of players in a non-existent list of players. However, when on element 2 of that list (the second player), you pop the second index from the list - Python however just knows that it was on the second element, you've just popped that, so now when it tries to get to the third element from the original list, that's no longer there - hence the end of the round.

Comment: If that comment is hard to understand, that may be partly due to a bad explanation, but I would argue it's the result of an overly complicated data structure that's poorly used - resulting in complicated and unexpected behaviour, even though Python is doing exactly what you're telling it to do.

Comment: For example, what’s up with `if len(NumberOfPlayers) == 1`?, inside `if PlayerEntry == CompNum`? The second line inside the statement is `PlayersForRound`.

Comment: @Grismar Out of respect for your time taken to help me with this out of the kindness of your heart, i will read the entirety of PEP8. Im usually a C# programmer, im just trying to help a friend with Python. Poor exscuse i know, i will rectify this. As for your answer regarding the iteration, I assume that this happens because Python for function looks for the next step in a list and since index 2 disappears from under it, it cant find the next in line? Is that correct? If so, how would i go about removing the player from the game for all further iterations?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Outo of respect for your time also, i will read up on some proper naming conventions for Python, apologies for making this so difficult.

Comment: @RustyUK What IDE are you using? Changing the names should be a breeze.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Visual Studio, Yes it will be a breeze, currently trying to do this for a friend whilst putting together Architecture for a new program. My mind is stretched between the two at the moment, among a million other things, you know how it goes.

Comment: @RustyUK Yeah, I can definitely relate. Good luck with the code, I’ll be back tomorrow :)

Comment: @AlexanderCécile As will i, with hopefully a solution and more readable code.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Thanks for your help with this, i will use it as an example of bad code and refactor it to be python esque standard. Take care.

Comment: @RustyUK Don’t thank me, I haven’t delivered on the promised refactoring yet :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are keeping track of players in the current round using a list of player numbers. So, if you start with three players, `PlayersForRound` will start as `[1,2,3]`.

You then proceed to loop over this list to give each player their turn by using `for Player in PlayersForRound`.  However, `PlayersForRound` and `NumberOfPlayers` are the exact same list (not a copy), so when you remove a player from one, it is removed from both.

Once a player guesses correctly, you remove them from the list you were looping over with `NumberOfPlayers.pop(Player-1)`. For example if the second player guesses correctly, you remove their "index" from the list and the resulting list is now `[1,3]`.

However, because Python is still looping over that same list, player 3 never gets their turn, because their "index" is now in the position where the "index" of player 2 was a moment ago.

You should not modify the list you're looping over, this will result in the weird behaviour you are seeing. If you want to modify that list, you could write a `while` loop that conditionally increases an index into the list and checks whether it exceeds the length of the list, but there are nicer patterns to follow to achieve the same result.

As for naming, please refer to https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ - specifically, your variables like `PlayersForRound` should be named `players_for_round`, but more importantly, you should name the variables so that they mean what they say. `NumberOfPlayers` suggests that it is an integer, containing the number of players, but instead it is a list of player numbers, etc.

The selected bits of your code below reproduce the problem, without all the fluff:

```
# this line isn't in your code, but it amounts to the same as entering '3'
Players = 3
NumberOfPlayers = []
for i in range(Players):
    NumberOfPlayers.append(i+1)

PlayersForRound = NumberOfPlayers

for Player in PlayersForRound:
    # this line is not in your code, but amounts to the second player guessing correctly:
    if Player == 2:
        NumberOfPlayers.pop(Player-1)
    if Player == 3:
        print('this never happens')

# this is why:
print(PlayersForRound, NumberOfPlayers)
```

Comment: Thanks Grismar, I will call it time right now, I will refactor all the code tomorrow, attempt to enact your solution before asking you what that would look like and hopefully you can see better implementation of it then and can tell me where i can yet improve :) Unlike you, I am north of the river and have a bit of a drive to get home. The M1 North out of Brizzy is never fun. Unless im on my bike, which i didnt bring today :(

Comment: Thanks for your assistance with this, I have resolved the issue by using len to create a new list for loop iteration allowing me to edit the number of players variable during the loop which then gets relisted when the loop is run again. I will look at the PEP8 stuff as you suggested, my apologies for posing a messy problem. You were instrumental. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you pop the list, you intervene in the for loop. Here, you can play with this and see yourself.

```
players = 3
player_list = []
for p in range(players):
    player_list.append(p + 1)

for player in player_list:
    print(player)
    if player == 2:
        print("popped:",player_list.pop(player-1))
```

**Output**

```
1
2
popped: 2
```